# how to build a website in DNN 5?

Tags: dotnetnuke-module

How can i develop a module containing three folders like admin,jobseeker and employer having there own functionality with user controls. Actully i want to develop a job site using DotNetNuke 5 ,how can i start ? How can i build the modules required for jobsite?

Please give me your most valuable guidelines on this.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Your question will be better received if you ask something more specific than "please do my job for me". Asking for someone else to complete the task you underbid for on rentacoder is not a good way to thrive here. Ask a specific question, and you'll get a specific answer.

Comment: You might be better off asking your question here: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/tabid/795/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to dive into the DotNetNuke website to get your self started lots of resources to dig up there - otherwise I might say hire someone to get you started or take some training classes online